# Spark docker image

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-build

I want to build a spark 2.4 docker image.I follow the steps as per the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images)

The command that i run to build the image

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -t spark2.4-imp build
```

Here is the output i get. Its stuck at that fetch forever

[image]

Any clue?

UPDATE:

Same is the issue when i execute the following command

> docket build -t spark2.4-imp -f
>   kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .

Comment: Are you working behind a (corporate) proxy?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort  Not really. In fact, when i do a wget, it works

Comment: That does not necessarily mean you are not behind a proxy. I had the same issue in my place of work, I could wget from my machine, but the docker daemon did not use the proxy which cause it to be unable to connect to the internet.Could you check for sure if you are behind a proxy? (See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831266/find-proxy-server-using-command-line)

Comment: I tried commands in the link that you provided. None of them fetch any result. Also the wget output does not indicate that there is a proxy (going by the explanation again in the link you gave)

Comment: You have done all the prerequisites (mainly DNS config I am curious about)?

Comment: I am not familiar about the prerequisites. Can you thrown some light?

Comment: In the link you mentioned it lists some prerequisites: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#prerequisites

Comment: Are those required for creating the image itself? Most of them are for running Spark on K8S and may not be for building the image itself

Comment: Yes that is correct, I assumed you are using kubernetes but that assumption i  wrong?

Comment: I will eventually use but i am stuck at building the docker image itself which has got nothing to do with K8S?

Comment: Have you tried completely restarting docker? (So not only the build process, but the whole docker daemon)

Comment: I could not figure out what could be the issue in my office network. Finally, i built the same on AWS instance and pushed to docker hub